# How to make Parallel call to 2 different methods in c#

Tags: asp.net, .net, c#-4.0

I Have 2 methods getReponseFromDb() & getResponsefromthirdParty() returning some data in datatable format. How can i make this request async and wait till both of them return result

```
public static datatable GetResult() {
      var task1 = getResponseFromDb();
      var task2 = getResponseFromThirdParty();
      ProcessResult(task1, task2);
}

public static datatable getResponseFromDB() {
    using(con SqlConnection = new SqlConnection()) {
       //get data from sql
    }
     returns datatable
}

public static datatable getResponseFromthirdParty() {
    //networkrequest
    //process to datatable
    //return datatable
}
```

Answer (score 0):

using System.Threading.Tasks;

/*Keep a list of all task*/

```
    List<Task<DataTable>> AllTasks = new List<Task<DataTable>>();
```

/*Call both functions in parallel*/

```
    Task<DataTable> t1 = new Task<DataTable>(() => getReponseFromDb());

    Task<DataTable> t2 = new Task<DataTable>(() => getResponseFromthirdParty());
    AllTasks.Add(t1);
    AllTasks.Add(t2);
    t1.Start();
    t2.Start();
```

/*Wait for completion of all task*/

```
    Task.WhenAll(AllTasks).ContinueWith(task => ProcessResult(AllTasks));
```

NOTE: Use different SqlConnection object for both tasks if connecting to same database or you might get an error!:)